# How to turn off "Please enter PIN" (Ubuntu, Desktop, 3G Modem)

Tags: ubuntu, modem, 3g

Upon having booted to my Ubuntu on my notebook which has an internal dial-up device for 3G network, which I don't use anymore, Ubuntu asks for my PIN for the SIM card.

How can I disable this PIN request?

Comment: Mobile Broadband deactivation has no effect. SIM card remove worked!